# Is the suspension space contractible?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, quotient-spaces

Let $X$ be a topological space.   The suspension of $X$, denoted $ΣX$, is the quotient
$CX / (X × ${$1$}$)$, where $CX$ is the cone on $X$, the quotient space $(X × [0, 1]) / (X × ${$0$}$)$.

Is $ΣX$ contractible. How can I prove this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A suspension is not in general contractible.  To see this, note that the suspension of $S^n$ is $S^{n + 1}$, which is not contractible.

Comment: Yes, that looks right.  See, for example, ["suspension" in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suspension_%28topology%29).  It's a way to start with one topological space and get another one.

Comment: Yes, although if all you need is one counterexample, you could just consider what happens when $X$ is $S^0$, which is just two points.

Comment: Yep, I did thanks

Comment: Actually, my guess is that if $\Sigma X$ is contractible, then so is $X$.